# Add welcome message to static block in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a welcome message ( Hello! Username ) in magento block.

I tried adding this code in CMS block:

```
{{block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"}}
```

but when i login in website, i seeing only Hello! and don't show the name of user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you to show  all pages???

Comment: Yes Amit :) can you help me?

Comment: Where are you  want to show this ???

Comment: I want to show in a block or in header.phtml. I have a template with grid960 and i want to add this in block or in header.phtml. If i use block i don't show the username, if i add cms block in header ( directly in code ) i show the name. I think than problem is in layout.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Add a page welcome_msg.phtml with this content

```
<div>
    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
            if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()));
            } else {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
            }
        }

        echo $this->_data['welcome']; ?></p>
</div>
```

at

> /app/design/frontend/default/YOUR THEME/template/page/html/

And then call it from the static block this way

> {{block type="page/html_header"
>   template="page/html/welcome_msg.phtml"}}

Comment: Hi Ashlesha and thank you for answer, sorry but for me not work it :( i show only welcome , but dont show the name of user...i show only in top link Welcome, User! but in block only welcome...

Comment: So is the username not showing up in the top links?
Did not get really what you want.

Comment: In top link i see the customer name, but in block no. I think i should add something via xml file in layout path...